# Bootstrap Scroll-spy and navbar-collapse not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a one page website in that website i am using scroll-spy and navbar-collapse but it is not working i am using bootstrap and jquery through cdn link in the header part i tried it in jsbin,jsfiddle and etc but not worked and also tried using different browsers like firefox internet explorer please help me with this problem

here is my code

```
<html>
<heaad>
  <title>ScrollSpy</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{
  margin: 0 ;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#mydv1{
  background-color:red;

}
#mydv2{
  background-color:green;
}
#mydv3{
  background-color:blue;
}
#mydv4{
  background-color:yellow;
}
#mydv5{
  background-color:black;
}
.itemdiv{
  width: 100%;
  height:500px;

}
</style>
</heaad>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">IamM@nd@r</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#mydv1">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mydv2">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mydv3">Page 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mydv4">Page 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mydv5">Page 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="mydv1" class="itemdiv">item 1</div>
    <div id="mydv2" class="itemdiv">item 2</div>
    <div id="mydv3" class="itemdiv">item 3</div>
    <div id="mydv4" class="itemdiv">item 4</div>
    <div id="mydv5" class="itemdiv">item 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Load jQuery before Bootstrap.

Comment: You need to downgrade jQuery as well (`"jquery": "1.9.1 - 2"`) as 3.0 isn't supported: See [bower.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json)

Comment: Not sure, but I think your JS script tags need to be reversed. Jquery needs to be before bootstrap.js. Also there seem to be an error with bootstrap js, it depends on jquery lower than version 3

Comment: @ IndieRok thanks mate but navbar-collapse still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.

1) Use a older version of jquery, like 2.2.4

2) Switch the order of your JS script tags. Jquery needs to be before bootstrap

3) Your `head` tag has a typo. You wrote `heaad`. Fix that.

4) Add `height:100%;` to the CSS `body` rule

5) Add an id to the div wrapping the `ul.nav`

6) Update the `data-target` attribute of the body tag to your newly added id

With this, everything will work

Full code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>ScrollSpy</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
body{
  margin: 0 ;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
}
#mydv1{
  background-color:red;

}
#mydv2{
  background-color:green;
}
#mydv3{
  background-color:blue;
}
#mydv4{
  background-color:yellow;
}
#mydv5{
  background-color:black;
}
.itemdiv{
  width: 100%;
  height:500px;

}
</style>

</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">IamM@nd@r</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar-example" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#mydv1">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mydv2">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mydv3">Page 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mydv4">Page 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mydv5">Page 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="mydv1" class="itemdiv">item 1</div>
    <div id="mydv2" class="itemdiv">item 2</div>
    <div id="mydv3" class="itemdiv">item 3</div>
    <div id="mydv4" class="itemdiv">item 4</div>
    <div id="mydv5" class="itemdiv">item 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```